# Name contained an invalid character using cref in the comment

Tags: c#, xml, comments

```
/// <summary>
/// ...
/// Use <cref="SiX_Dg_RequestStop"/> function to stop this function from another thread.
/// </summary>
public static void SiX_Dg_Execute()
{
}

public static void SiX_Dg_RequestStop()
{
}
```

`cref` link in this code gives the following compiler warning:

```
C:\Project\file.cs(1337,22): warning CS1570: XML comment on 'AtpDotNet.ATP.SiX_Dg_Execute()' has badly formed XML -- 'A name contained an invalid character.'
```

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this isn't valid XML (node name is missing):

```
<cref="SiX_Dg_RequestStop"/>
```

Change it to:

```
<see cref="SiX_Dg_RequestStop"/>
```